# Elementwise summation of list entries in R

Tags: r, list

I have about 6000 list entries all with the same format and dimension. I want to sum the list entries to create one matrix where we obtain the following

```
entry [1,1] = list[[1]][1,1]+....+list[[6000]][1,1],
```

and

```
entry [1,2] = list[[1]][1,2]+....+list[[6000]][1,2]
```

etcetera. I have as reproducible example:

```
list_example <- list()
for(i in 1:100){
  list_example[[i]] <- rnorm(100,0,1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Reduce` like below

```
Reduce(`+`, list_example)
```

or `sapply` + `data.table::transpose`

```
sapply(data.table::transpose(list_example), sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Coerce to `matrix` then `rowSums`.

```
rowSums(matrix(unlist(list_example), ncol=length(list_example)))
# [1] 3.452629 1.049781 4.562073
```

Or using `colSums` after `rbind`.

```
colSums(do.call(rbind, list_example))
# [1] 3.452629 1.049781 4.562073
```

---

**Data**

For the sake of clarity I use a smaller list here.

```
set.seed(42)
list_example <- list()
for(i in 1:4){
  list_example[[i]] <- rnorm(3,0,1)
}
```

---

```
set.seed(42)
list_example <- list()
for(i in seq(1e5)) {list_example[[i]] <- rnorm(3,0,1)}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(list2DF=rowSums(list2DF(list_example)),
                               rowSums=rowSums(matrix(unlist(list_example), ncol=length(list_example))),
                               Reduce=Reduce(`+`, list_example),
                               data.table=sapply(data.table::transpose(list_example), sum),
                               data.table2=unlist(lapply(data.table::transpose(list_example), sum)),
                               data.table3=vapply(data.table::transpose(list_example), sum, 0),
                               colSums=colSums(do.call(rbind, list_example)),
                               times=100L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval  cld
#     list2DF 736.073711 771.667592 803.028556 795.729308 830.898798 920.98592   100    d
#     rowSums   7.848909   7.943765   9.436778   8.002277   8.085766 106.27099   100 a   
#      Reduce  60.616783  65.026398  70.332936  68.337665  71.649778 136.14140   100  b  
#  data.table   6.371089   6.508093   7.447124   6.671454   6.846889  73.26115   100 a   
# data.table2   6.286547   6.433442   7.792743   6.578557   6.842724  96.99866   100 a   
# data.table3   6.254795   6.447059   6.796695   6.597071   6.796004  13.22731   100 a   
#     colSums  60.533471  69.789563  89.329641  78.337311  95.657619 232.72070   100   c
```

Comment: Nice approach, upvoted! Also, maybe we can use `rowSums(list2DF(list_example))` if we want to use `rowSums`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding  See benchmark, I have also included `list2DF` but it is slow. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting benchmarking! Maybe `sapply(data.table::transpose(list_example), sum)` can be another option.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Finally came up with a `rowSums` solution which is much faster! See edit.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Put `data.table` to your answer! It's fastest, I tried different `*apply` variants, but it's rather inconclusive which is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(list_example, `+`)
```